# Need help matching specific area codes only? What are my options/possibilities?

Tags: regex

I use \d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4} to match numbers such as 212-555-1234

However, I dont want to match numbers like 555-555-1234 or 123-555-1234, I would only like to specifically use a regex to match numbers that START with the following area codes only. How can it be done?

201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 224 225 226 227 228 229 231 234 236 239 240 242 246 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 256 260 262 264 267 268 269 270 272 274 276 281 283 284 289 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 323 325 327 330 331 332 334 336 337 339 340 343 345 346 347 351 352 360 361 364 365 380 385 386 387 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 423 424 425 430 431 432 434 435 437 438 440 441 442 443 447 450 458 463 464 469 470 473 475 478 479 480 484 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 530 531 534 539 540 541 548 551 559 561 562 563 564 567 570 571 573 574 575 579 580 581 585 586 587 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 623 626 628 629 630 631 636 639 641 646 647 649 650 651 657 660 661 662 664 667 669 670 671 672 678 680 681 682 684 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 724 725 727 730 731 732 734 737 740 742 743 747 754 757 758 760 762 763 765 767 769 770 772 773 774 775 778 779 780 781 782 782 784 785 786 787 801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 812 813 814 815 816 817 818 819 825 828 829 830 831 832 843 845 847 848 849 850 854 856 857 858 859 860 862 863 864 865 867 868 869 870 872 873 876 878 901 902 902 903 904 905 906 907 908 909 910 912 913 914 915 916 917 918 919 920 925 928 929 930 931 934 936 937 938 939 940 941 947 949 951 952 954 956 959 970 971 972 973 975 978 979 980 984 985 986 989

Comment: What is your input like? If it's always like "123-456-7890", you could just split the string and check if the first part is present in a list of your valid numbers.

Comment: Is this for a one-off extraction of matching phone numbers or is this something you're planning on putting into production code? I'm asking, because if speed isn't a huge concern for you, you could just make a really long regex that encompasses those area codes.

Comment: which technology are you using with the regex? I think you should use a regex like `(\d{3})\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})` and if it matches just look forthe first capturing group in an array of your numbers.

Comment: I am not using php. I match the above regex in notepad+ and bookmark them, however iI need a specific match matching the numbers above

Comment: Notepad++ has it's own regex flavour, which is documented here: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Rollback to Revision 2, because Revision 3 gives the false impression that 204

[...]

986 were a range including all numbers in between.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you can't just use alternation in the regex.

```
(201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|220|224|225|226|227|228|229|231|234|236|239|240|242|246|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|256|260|262|264|267|268|269|270|272|274|276|281|283|284|289|301|302|303|304|305|306|307|308|309|310|312|313|314|315|316|317|318|319|320|321|323|325|327|330|331|332|334|336|337|339|340|343|345|346|347|351|352|360|361|364|365|380|385|386|387|401|402|403|404|405|406|407|408|409|410|412|413|414|415|416|417|418|419|423|424|425|430|431|432|434|435|437|438|440|441|442|443|447|450|458|463|464|469|470|473|475|478|479|480|484|501|502|503|504|505|506|507|508|509|510|512|513|514|515|516|517|518|519|520|530|531|534|539|540|541|548|551|559|561|562|563|564|567|570|571|573|574|575|579|580|581|585|586|587|601|602|603|604|605|606|607|608|609|610|612|613|614|615|616|617|618|619|620|623|626|628|629|630|631|636|639|641|646|647|649|650|651|657|660|661|662|664|667|669|670|671|672|678|680|681|682|684|701|702|703|704|705|706|707|708|709|712|713|714|715|716|717|718|719|720|721|724|725|727|730|731|732|734|737|740|742|743|747|754|757|758|760|762|763|765|767|769|770|772|773|774|775|778|779|780|781|782|782|784|785|786|787|801|802|803|804|805|806|807|808|809|810|812|813|814|815|816|817|818|819|825|828|829|830|831|832|843|845|847|848|849|850|854|856|857|858|859|860|862|863|864|865|867|868|869|870|872|873|876|878|901|902|902|903|904|905|906|907|908|909|910|912|913|914|915|916|917|918|919|920|925|928|929|930|931|934|936|937|938|939|940|941|947|949|951|952|954|956|959|970|971|972|973|975|978|979|980|984|985|986|989)\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4}
```